# initializing static field to be available throughout application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

In one of requirement we have to make available certain attributes through out the web-application so that we can show them in the drop down where ever we want them.So we have few options
We are planning to create a utility class with some static fields which will be assigned values at application startup or when the first request for that list arrived.
Idea is to read a property file and create a `List<String>` and assign it to the static field so that when ever some one need access to it all he/she need the following call

```
GeneralUtil.getList()
```

Since we are working in a web-application one option is to create a listner like

```
public final class MyListener
   implements ServletContextListener {

}
```

and than read the property file on the `contextInitialized` method and assign the read value to the static field so that they will be available after startup.

other option is
to create a static block inside  `GeneralUtil` class and place the file read logic inside the static block so that once the class loaded by the cotainer static field will be initialize and we need not to load it for subsequent request.

my question is which of these should be preferred approach and if there is any other best way to achieve this.All i want to avoid to place List in `ApplicationContext` or any such approach.

Comment: Why you don't want to put it on `ApplicationContext`?

Comment: @JigarJoshiThis makes me less dependent on the context and how the context works. Makes my application less troublesome to move if i, for some reason

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go with the `ServletContextListener` approach and an accessor for your property. It seems cleaner and more intuitive than static initializer block.

I would find it also easier if in the future you would like to separate the initialization logic into several methods. In separate class with well defined responsibility it will be easier to do (and to read!) than in some 'GeneralUtil god-like class'.

If you're limited to Servlets I think that's the best and simplest solution.

However, if you're working with EJB's you could as well use `@Singleton` EJB with `@Startup`. If you're working with CDI you could use `@ApplicationScoped` CDI bean.

HTH.

Comment: +1 for your point to future need of seperatin the initialization logic

Answer (score 2):

> and than read the property file on the contextInitialized method and assign the read value to the static field so that they will be available after startup.

Instead of static variables,place the created `List<String>` in the `servletContext` object at `contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce)` method

Note that you could retrieve the `servletContext` object from `ServletContextEvent`.

Comment: that will just coupled my code with the ServletContext and anytime i have to get depedent with the Context itself

Answer (score 1):

The static solution would mean ThreadLocal and using serialization.

A application scoped bean (yeah, probably best placed in the ApplicationContext) would make the most sense. You could still wrap it in a kind of GeneralUtil wrapper. The solution of Piotr Nowicki is best.

I think you did not want to hear this solution.

Comment: i am not sure what exactly you mean by "The static solution would mean ThreadLocal and using serialization.

"

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you want to add these values in ApplicationContext ? It makes sense since its going to be same for whole of the application ?

Of the two option you have mentioned its better to load these properties in MyListener instead of static block, reasoning if your load fails your GeneralUtil class wont be loaded unless you specifically catch exception and ignore it, which means application cannot be used.

Comment: +1 for the exception things.i somehow ignored that.Thanks for puting this point

Comment: :) move the counter from 0 to 1 of useful answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've used a ServletContextListener for a similar use case and it worked out just fine. I think this is the easiest and most straightforward solution. Just put the attributes into the `ServletContext` via `setAttribute(name, object)` and retrieve them anywhere in your application via `getAttribute(name)`.

Comment: i will not prefer to put them in ServletContext as putting them means making my application tied with the context throughput